# Trigger an UP or DOWN ARROW key event through javascript

Tags: javascript

There is some event listener in Thunderbird which resolves the emails address from my LDAP server when i press the UP or DOWN ARROW key.
so i want to trigger that the same event through Javascript without having to physically press the up or down arrow key.
How can i do this?

Comment: Do you have code that attempts to do this, but doesn't work how you expect it to?

Comment: no i do not have code .. i wanted to know i can i simulate the up and down arrow key through javascript..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is what you want (using JQuery)

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");

// e.which is used to set the keycode
e.which = 38; // it is up
e.which = 40; // it is down
$("id_to_element").trigger(e);
```

If JQuery is not allowed to use, pure javascript solution is more verbose. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12187302/2648754)

Note: There maybe a bug in Chrome which will hamper this. I would recommend JQuery for less headache.

Comment: Thanks Akash for the help this is exactly what i want but for javascript not for jquery. If you can please provide me some info in how can i do it through javascript.

Comment: Updated answer. Follow the link.