# Javascript Trigger "right arrow" key event - Force Label Deselection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to trigger a keyboard event to press "right arrow" key. The purpose is to cancel the highlight.

I used the code below to insert a hyper link into the editor content.

```
var range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var nnode = document.createElement("a");
range.surroundContents(nnode);
nnode.innerHTML = url;
nnode.setAttribute(url);
nnode.focus();
```

[image: html]

It is highlight by default. I want to trigger an "right arrow" key in order to cancel the highlight and move the cursor to the right. I did many searchs, I tried the most of solutions, but I still get one works. My environment is IE 11.

Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Comment: X-Y problem. You don't want to *Trigger "right arrow"*, your second sentence is what you want: "The purpose is to cancel the highlight." and for this, you really don't need to *Trigger "right arrow"*.

Comment: Simulating such user input events has never been universally supported and has been eschewed in more recent years. There is no appropriate cross-browser solution to the “X” question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. here are the resources you're asking for, but I have a solution for your highlighting problem which is none of these.

**Resources**:

[How to trigger click on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060019/how-to-trigger-click-on-page-load)

[Detecting arrow key presses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript)

[Trigger an UP or DOWN ARROW key event through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347883/trigger-an-up-or-down-arrow-key-event-through-javascript)

The actual solution uses JQuery & this resource: [JavaScript Set Window selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190143/javascript-set-window-selection)

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
I am some text!
</div>
```

See the JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wonjqe7/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try tomorow since I don't have access to my computer right now. BTW, will this solution keep the cursor at the right end of the string? Or, is there a another way to just focus on the right end of the string?

Comment: The cursor will not appear when this code is run, is that what you were after? It will just be as though the text was never selected

Comment: Thanks so much! Your solution perfectly solved my problem.